# Wrong Local time Archlinux + Xfce4

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, date, time

My system **local clock** has been displayed incorrectly for several days. when i run `timedatectl status` output is something like this :

```
 ➜ timedatectl status
Local time: Sat 2021-12-25 19:16:57 +0330
Universal time: Sat 2021-12-25 15:46:57 UTC
RTC time: Sat 2021-12-25 15:46:57
Time zone: Asia/Tehran (+0330, +0330)
System clock synchronized: no
NTP service: active
RTC in local TZ: no
```

Universal time and RTC time is correct but value of **Local time** is incorrect !

**local time** fixs after run `sudo ntpd -qg` .

But when i restart system Everything goes back and goes wrong ...

How can i solve this problem ?

this is more information of my system :
i use arch+xfce4
the output of `timedatectl timesync-status` is :

```
Server: n/a (ur.ntp.srv)
Poll interval: 0 (min: 32s; max 34min 8s)
 Packet count: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just run `hwclock --systohc` in terminal to set the hardware clock from the system clock and my problem fixed.

According this [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/System_time#Set_hardware_clock_from_system_clock) from arch documantation problem was about hardware clock

Answer (score 1):

`ur.ntp.srv` is not a real [NTP server](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Network_Time_Protocol_daemon#Connection_to_NTP_servers) but looks more like a request to insert the domain of a NTP server of your choice. So you probably changed your configuration following some tutorial.
In Arch Linux the default [systemd-timesyncd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd-timesyncd) fallback server should just work so it's not necessary to change `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf`.

You can check with `pacman -Qii systemd` if you have modified the file. And if so you can compare the unmodified version by using the following command:

```
tar xOf /var/cache/pacman/pkg/systemd-$(pacman -Q systemd | awk '{print $2}')-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf | diff /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf -
```

After fixing the NTP server configuration you can enable systemd-timesyncd with `sudo timedatectl set-ntp true` (alternatively you can enable `ntpd`)